# how do i get the value of an array encoded using http_build_query()

Tags: php

i have an array

Array

```
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11-11-111
            [branch_id] => 
            [last_name] => Doe
            [first_name] => Jhon
            [middle_name] => Mcdonald
        )

    [UserOrder] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0-01-66168-21                     
                    [user_id] => 11-11-111
                    [date_requested] => 2011-11-16
                    [time_requested] => 15:39:08
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0-03-65692-13
                    [patient_id] => 11-11-111
                    [date_requested] => 2011-11-07
                    [time_requested] => 06:48:08
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0-08-56323-24
                    [patient_id] => 11-11-111
                    [date_requested] => 2011-11-07
                    [time_requested] => 07:09:28
                )

        )

)
```

i have used http_build_query() for this to be accepted in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Is there a way i can revert it back to its array form? if not, how can i get the value of each array using $_POST?

Any suggestion will be very much appreciated!, thank you in advance! cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any transformations to pass a PHP structure to curl. It will accept an array directly:

```
 $array = (.... your structure here ...);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
```

and curl will handle the encoding itself. However, if you insist on doing it yourself, then try [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) or [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url).

Comment: im getting an error like this one "Array to string conversion".

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`http_build_str`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/http_build_str):

```
$str = http_build_str($arr);
```

The function takes care to properly build a queryinfo-part like encoding of an array as can be dealt with by PHP.

For your example data:

> User%5Bid%5D=11-11-111&User%5Bbranch_id%5D=&User%5Blast_name%5D=Doe&User%5Bfirst_name%5D=Jhon&User%5Bmiddle_name%5D=Mcdonald&UserOrder%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=0-01-66168-21&UserOrder%5B0%5D%5Buser_id%5D=11-11-111&UserOrder%5B0%5D%5Bdate_requested%5D=2011-11-16&UserOrder%5B0%5D%5Btime_requested%5D=15%3A39%3A08&UserOrder%5B1%5D%5Bid%5D=0-03-65692-13&UserOrder%5B1%5D%5Bpatient_id%5D=11-11-111&UserOrder%5B1%5D%5Bdate_requested%5D=2011-11-07&UserOrder%5B1%5D%5Btime_requested%5D=06%3A48%3A08&UserOrder%5B2%5D%5Bid%5D=0-08-56323-24&UserOrder%5B2%5D%5Bpatient_id%5D=11-11-111&UserOrder%5B2%5D%5Bdate_requested%5D=2011-11-07&UserOrder%5B2%5D%5Btime_requested%5D=07%3A09%3A28

You need to have the [HTTP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) installed for that function.

Comment: how can i get the value of my array using $_POST after performing http_build_str?

Comment: Use that string as post body, you have it in `$_POST` then, like the original array.

Comment: is there a way i could revert it back in its original form? (array form)

Comment: `$_POST` is in array form. The string as in the answer can be converted with http://de.php.net/parse_str as well.